# EasyGui diropenbox() give error 'module' object has no attribute 'askdirectory'

Tags: python, easygui

I have a Python script calling easygui.  This script worked fine on my previous computer.  I have a new computer and I am trying to upgrade my script but not I get an error from easygui.
Here is the offending code.

```
inDir = diropenbox("Set to the input directory of geo-tagged images.  This directory will also store the output KML file.")
```

Here is the error message.

```
PYTHON ERRORS:
Traceback info:
  File "C:\gTemp\GeotaggedImagesToKMLandCSVforLiNUXandiOS\GeotaggedImage2KML_CSV.py", line 150, in <module>
inDir = diropenbox()

Error Info:
'module' object has no attribute 'askdirectory'
```

Why would the code now throw this error? Note-earlier in the code I call easygui textbox and that works so I believe the installation is fine.
Python 2.7
Windows 7
easygui_0.98.1-py2.py3-none.any.whl installed.

Answer (score 0):

Removing easygui 0.98 and installing 0.97 fixed the problem.